# Post a question to generate tag wikis

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

Over on Sustainability.SE we just issued [a call for tag wikis](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/q/384/3379). Historically, we've struggled to generate tag wikis, and those we do have aren't always great.

To address this problem (in addition to the meta post), I wondered about a different method to encourage people to contribute to tag wikis: **Post a question on the main site asking for the definition and usage of [tag].**

- Use a title like "What is [tag], and how does it relate to [site topic]?"
- A tag like [tag-wiki-generator](/questions/tagged/tag-wiki-generator) could be used to identify the questions
- After a while, the top-voted answer could be edited into the tag wiki

I understand that this would be *borderline* off-topic for most sites. A question like "What is jQuery?" would get closed in a heartbeat on SO, and rightfully so. But on a smaller site and for more niche topics, such definition questions are often on topic. For instance, on Sustainability.SE we have a well-used tag for [defining-sustainability](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/defining-sustainability).

This approach has a few benefits I can see:

- The topic discussion would be much more visible than a post on per-site meta
- People would be more likely to vote, and answers would earn rep for the posters, giving some motivation to contribute

---

Obviously, before implementing this we'd have to discuss on our per-site meta, but I wanted to propose the idea here to get some feedback from those active on other sites.

Some discussion questions:

- Have other sites tried this? What were the results?
- Any other benefits to this approach?
- Any drawbacks I'm not seeing?